# Should I have different toggles for collecting usage data and crash reports?

Tags: privacy, statistics

I am developing a mobile app and I am currently working on the usage and crash report functionalities, which made me start wondering: should I ask the user two different permissions for these features, i.e. one for collecting general usage stats and one for collecting crash reports only?

Would this make sense? Would this increase the perception of transparency that users would get from my app? Or would it simply be overkill and I should just condense both options under a "share usage stats" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself what would you do?

---

**If I was using the app:**

- Share Usage Data (*Unchecked*)
- Report Crash Logs (*Checked*)
- Share Usage Stats (*Unchecked*)

Someone else might do something else.

**You need to set your priorities:**

- Make user feel that you value `Transparency` at all cost.
- Improve your app quality by collecting `Crash Reports` at all cost
- Improve Quality and Business by collecting `Usage Data` and `Crash Reports` at all cost.

---

**Make it simple not simpler:**

Two checkbox are OK, and this can accomplish all three goals (let the user choose)

- If they choose both (they happy, you haapy)
- If they choose one (makes sense, still both happy)
- If none chosen (user happy, and your transparency is into play)